# Sendgrid not recieving emails

Tags: kubernetes

I recently setup a new Sendgrid account and changed the server environment variable in the GCP Kubernetes configmap to the new Sendgrid key. The application was working fine before chaging the configmap sendgrid api key.  Nothing else in the setup was changed other than the configmap sendgrid api key.

I have included small snippet of the code regarding the sendgrid.

Any reason whey the application is unable to send email, could it be something to do with the Kubernetes configmap and the PODS not reading the updated configmap

Any advice is appreciated.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
SENDGRID_API_KEY: SG.dxla2QIpRDSS64cb8YC_vQ.4rzONm8iv_GLdbJfXQdlrVRyTWQnFQ5R1Tntpg 
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-05-30T11:37:43Z"
  labels:
    app: ubackend
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        .: {}
        f:SENDGRID_API_KEY: {}         
    manager: GoogleCloudConsole
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-09-25T16:59:46Z"
  name: backend-config-k311
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "79059321"
  uid: 1990cf82-931c-48f7-80c2-b99d09970a0a



   static async forgotPassword (request, response) {
    try {
      const { userName } = request.body
      const { email } = request.body
      let user
      if (userName) {
        user = await User.findOne({userName: userName })
      }
      if (email) {
        user = await User.findOne({ email: email })
      }
      if (user) {
        const random = new Random()
        const userEmail = user.email
        const verificationCode = random.integer(100000,999999)
        await User.updateOne({ email: userEmail}, { passwordResetCode: verificationCode, updated: Date.now()})
        const mailer = new MailController()
        mailer.sendPasswordResetCode(verificationCode, user)
        const emailMasked = maskEmail(userEmail)
        return response.json({ success: true, message: `reset code send to ${emailMasked}`, emailMasked })
      } else {
        return response.json({ success: false, message: 'No account found' })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      LoggerHelper.error({ action: 'forgotPassword', error: error.message })
      return response.status(301).json({success: false, error: 'some error happened. please try again later'})
    }



  sendPasswordResetCode (code, user) {
    const mailOptions = {
      from: '"testdomain" <verify@testdomain.com.au>',
      to: user.email,
      subject: 'password reset',
      text: 'password reset',
      html: `<h2>Reset your password</h2><h3>your username: <b>${user.userName}</b></h3><h3>your code: <b>${code}</b></h3>`
    }

    sgEmail.send(mailOptions).then(() => {       
      loggerHelper.info(`password reset ${user.email}`)
      return true
    }).catch((error) => {
      loggerHelper.error(error.response.body.errors)
      return false
    }) 
  }
```

Comment: I don't see your code snippet uses `SENDGRID_API_KEY` environment variable. Also, applications usually need to be restarted in order to get any updates on any attached `ConfigMap`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think we found the problem. In our applictionn we wer sending from verify@testdomain.com.au but the single sender authentiction was setup for info@testdomain.com.au, hence when our application was sending with verify@testdomain.com.au it was not authorized by sendgrid and was rejecting it.